# Why is my "tar"-command not working because it is refusing to create an empty archive?

Tags: shell, backup, tar

tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

And these are my Commands:

```
tar -cz -newer $letztes_full_backup -f $zielpfad/inc_backup_home_$datum.tar.gz/home
tar -czf $zielpfad/full_backup_$datum.tar.gz/home
tar -czf $zielpfad/full_backup_$datum.tar.gz/home
```

Comment: It sounds like your commands would result in an empty result being created, which tar doesn't want to do, but there isn't enough information to reproduce what's happening.

Comment: You don't provide any files to put into your archive. You would get the same error message if you just do a `tar -cz`. It's not clear to me what you want to achieve.